# : CommandLine Error: Option 'help-list' registered more than once! LLVM ERROR: inconsistency in registered CommandLine options

Tags: llvm

It seems there are llvm multiple versions, but how can I found exist installed versions?

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -qa|grep -i llvm
llvm-12.0.1-2.module_el8.5.0+918+ed335b90.x86_64
llvm-libs-12.0.1-2.module_el8.5.0+918+ed335b90.x86_64
```

Comment: One reasonable way may be to look for a file name within LLVM that is unlikely to exist in other software, such as GlobalValue.h. Running `locate GlobalValue.h` shows me three files on my work machine, each within one installation of LLVM.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.